# Can I show files in a directory while filtering certain formats in a batch file (cmd)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

Here's a very simple question. I want to show all the files in a certain directory on a batch file. I've already written some code:

```
dir /b /a-d
```

But all this does is give me this type of output.
(example)

```
file1.txt
video.mp4
jams.mp3
```

Is there a way that I could filter out the '.mp3' files in pure  batch code?

Comment: Filtering only `.mp3` files would no longer show all files in the directory, unless there were only `.mp3` files in there! If you want to know how to use the `dir` command, open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information. Your question is off topic, because you clearly have made no attempt at performing the basic research before posting. In addition, please note that using a glob, such as `*.mp3`, will potentially show other files too, due to 8.3 naming.

Comment: @Compo I understand that `*.mp3` works. But I want to know how to filter **_out_** certain formats, not only display one format.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information. Also we have a search facility at the top of each page of the site, please use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you could use, `Dir` with `findstr.exe`.

For example:

```
Dir /B/A-D | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /EILV ".mp3"
```

And you could also use `powershell.exe`:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile Get-ChildItem -Exclude "*.mp3" -File -Name -Force
```

Depending upon your required layout and purposes you could also use:

`forfiles.exe`:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C If @IsDir==FALSE If /I Not @Ext==\"mp3\" Echo @File"
```

Or even `Robocopy.exe`:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe . Null /L /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /XF "*.mp3"
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with DIR and FIND.EXE. Read about what /I and /V do using the command `FIND /?`.

```
DIR /B /A:-D | FIND /I /V ".mp3"
```

If you wanted to use a modern-day tool, you could do it with PowerShell, even while running it from a pure batch file script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object { @('.mp3') -notcontains $_.Extension }).Name"
```